# I would like to print superscript and subscript with printf, like x¹?

Tags: c, unicode, polynomials, subscript, superscript

I want to print out a **polynomial** expression in c but i don't know print x to the power of a number with `printf`

Comment: Apices don't belong to the ASCII set, so you won't able to print them with printf. Try using  a notation like x^2.

Comment: Most consoles don't support formatting like that. So if it is possible depends on if some certain OS supports it, which I'm not aware of off the top of my head.

Comment: Good question and I did not find a dup, so I edited it so it's easier for others to find.

Comment: Note: you cannot do it in a proper way. You have an hack on the answers, but you should not use formatting in Unicode: you must use a formatting protocol (html, restructured-text, tex, ... Unicode has support of them, just for compatibility of old data, it should not be used for new texts. In facts, you cannot put many letters as subscripts, and you cannot put in parallel different ones.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: `printf` is neither limited to ASCII nor required to use it. C implementations are free to support UTF-8, for example, or to use EBCDIC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's far from trivial unfortunately. You cannot achieve what you want with `printf`. You need `wprintf`. Furthermore, it's not trivial to translate between normal and superscript. You would like a function like this:

```
wchar_t digit_to_superscript(int d) {
    wchar_t table[] = { // Unicode values
        0x2070, 
        0x00B9,         // Note that 1, 2 and 3 does not follow the pattern
        0x00B2,         // That's because those three were common in various
        0x00B3,         // extended ascii tables. The rest did not exist
        0x2074,         // before unicode
        0x2075,
        0x2076,
        0x2077,
        0x2078,
        0x2079,
    };

    return table[d];
}
```

This function could of course be changed to handle other characters too, as long as they are supported. And you could also write more complete functions operating on complete strings.

But as I said, it's not trivial, and it cannot be done with simple format strings to `printf`, and not even to `wprintf`.

Here is a somewhat working example. It's usable, but it's very short because I have omitted all error checking and such. Shortest possible to be able to use a negative float number as exponent.

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

wchar_t char_to_superscript(wchar_t c) {
    wchar_t digit_table[] = {
        0x2070, 0x00B9, 0x00B2, 0x00B3, 0x2074, 
        0x2075, 0x2076, 0x2077, 0x2078, 0x2079,
    };

    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') return digit_table[c - '0'];
    switch(c) {
        case '.': return 0x22C5; 
        case '-': return 0x207B;
    }
}

void number_to_superscript(wchar_t *dest, wchar_t *src) {
    while(*src){
        *dest = char_to_superscript(*src);
        src++;
        dest++;
    }
    dest++;
    *dest = 0;
}
```

And a main function to demonstrate:

```
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    double x = -3.5;
    wchar_t wstr[100], a[100];
    swprintf(a, 100, L"%f", x);
    wprintf(L"Number as a string: %ls\n", a);
    number_to_superscript(wstr, a);
    wprintf(L"Number as exponent: x%ls\n", wstr);
}
```

Output:

```
Number as a string: -3.500000
Number as exponent: x⁻³⋅⁵⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰
```

In order to make a complete translator, you would need something like this:

```
size_t superscript_index(wchar_t c) {
    // Code
}

wchar_t to_superscript(wchar_t c) {
    static wchar_t huge_table[] {
         // Long list of values
    };

    return huge_table[superscript_index(c)];
}
```

Remember that this cannot be done for all characters. Only those whose counterpart exists as a superscript version.

Comment: i thought it would be easier

Comment: What are these values and where they come from?

Comment: Re “`printf` cannot handle unicode”: The C standard imposes no such limitations. Typical `printf` implementations can handle arbitrary non-zero codes, treating them as raw binary aside from the interpretations (for conversion specifiers and such) required by the C standard and so are agnostic about whether the data being printed is ASCII, UTF-8, or something else. And UTF-8 is designed to fit in this model, such as by not using bytes in its encodings that are zero or ASCII (high bit is zero) except for, of course, the null character and ASCII characters.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Would you say that you can achieve the output here with `printf` instead of `wprintf`?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to output formatted text with `printf`.

(Of course one could output HTML format, but this then would need to be fed into an interpreter first for correct display)

So you cannot print text in superscript format in the general case.

What you have found is the superscript 1 as a special character. However this is only possible with 1 and 2, if I remember correctly (and only for the right code-page, not in plain ASCII).

The common way to print "superscripts" is to use the `x^2`, `x^3` syntax. This is commonly understood.

An alternative is provided by klutt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65989147/1739884). If you switch to unicode by using `wprintf` instead of `printf` you could use all superscript characters from 0 to 9. Even though, I am not sure how multi-digit exponents look like in a fixed-width terminal it works in principle.

Comment: In pure ascii, not even 1 and 2 are possible. But 1,2 and 3 were possible in various extended ascii tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print superscript 1, you need to use unicode. You can combine unicode superscripts to write a multi-digit number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wchar_t one = 0x00B9;
    wchar_t two = 0x00B2;
    wprintf(L"x%lc\n", one);
    wprintf(L"x%lc%lc\n", one, two);
}
```

Output:

```
$ clang ~/lab/unicode.c 
$ ./a.out 
x¹
x¹²
```

Ref: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B9